# Replace MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) battery from MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

The macbook i am using currently is MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012). Now the battery warning is "Replace now" state. So i need to change it. I have another macbook with MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011).

Is it possible the replace battery from MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) to MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to iFixit they would appear to be the same part.

Refs:
[MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Early 2011 Battery Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Battery+Replacement/5116)
[MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Mid 2012 Battery Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Battery+Replacement/10365)

and their advert on both pages...

[image]

Comment: Yes, i already have seen it. Let it be confirmed more. I will accept your answer then. BTW, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to swap the battery from a MacBook Pro 13" (Early 2011) to a MacBook Pro 13" (Mid 2012) model. In fact, the same battery is used from Mid 2009 to Mid 2012 in all 13" MacBook Pros. You will need a special screwdriver called a tri-wing screwdriver though, to remove and reinstall the battery.